# jQuery mobile: dynamically filled DropDown-List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am filling a dropdown list dynamically with jQuery mobile. But the problem is: There is no entry preselected at start, it is just emtpy. The user has to tap on the dropdown and select the first entry to select it. But it should be pre selected - is there any way/problem with this? Heres the Dropdown:

```
            <select name="selectQuestion" id="selectQuestionReset">
```

Here the code which fills it:

```
$.post('url, { }, function(data){
    data = $.trim(data);
    $('#selectQuestionReg').empty();

    if(data.length>1){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        data.forEach(function(i) {
            $('<option value="' + i.frage + '" id="' + i.id + '">' + i.frage + '</option>').appendTo($('#selectQuestionReg'));
            $('#selectQuestionReg').trigger("chosen:updated");
        })
    }else{
        jError(
            'Fehler beim Anfordern der Sicherheitsfragen!',
            {
                autoHide : true, 
                TimeShown : 2000,
                HorizontalPosition : 'center',
                VerticalPosition : 'top'
            }); 
    }
```

that's how it looks like:http://s14.directupload.net/images/140223/6wu87wge.jpg
there should be the first option already displayed as selected..

Answer (score 0):

You  can append one more option tag before your response..
1) `<option value="0">Select option<option>`OR 
2) `<option value="0"><option>`

When you submit the form that time validate with "0" value of the drop down list.  like
`if($('#selectQuestionReg').val()==0){
   alert("Please select option");
}`
`$.post('url, { }, function(data){
    data = $.trim(data);
    $('#selectQuestionReg').empty();

```
if(data.length>1){
    data = JSON.parse(data);
```

$('#selectQuestionReg').html("Select Option");// here your before exists data removed and added new data
        data.forEach(function(i) {
            $('' + i.frage + '').appendTo($('#selectQuestionReg'));
            $('#selectQuestionReg').trigger("chosen:updated");
        })
    }else{
        jError(
            'Fehler beim Anfordern der Sicherheitsfragen!',
            {
                autoHide : true, 
                TimeShown : 2000,
                HorizontalPosition : 'center',
                VerticalPosition : 'top'
            }); 
    }`